# Google Maps API on Wordpress Website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, maps

I have a problem on my wordpress website. Even though I get the API key for my website. When I copy and paste this code

```
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to header.php or contact-map.php I still get the error "opps something went wrong, check javascript details"

Sometimes the map shows up sometimes it doesn't.

What can I do to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Make it with iframe, use this guide

https://en.support.wordpress.com/google-maps/
will look something like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d274111.9525856589!2d11.682992776037743!3d57.53793160817174!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x464f8e67966c073f%3A0x4019078290e7c40!2zR8O2dGVib3Jn!5e0!3m2!1ssv!2sse!4v1467106079613" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```